# Python error: "break is outside the loop"

Tags: python

This is a program to book tickets for a movie online. The output shows "break is outside the loop". What should I change to correct this?

```
viewers = []
class TenetMovie:
def __init__(self,movie_name):
    self.movie_name=movie_name


    def ticket_buyer(self):
        print('at any point if you want to exit press "q"') 
        your_name = input("your name : ")
        if your_name == 'q':
            break
        no_of_tickets = input("how many tickets : ")
        if no_of_tickets == 'q':
            break
        seats = input("select the seats : ")
        if seats == 'q':
            break
        viewers.extend((self.movie_name,your_name,no_of_tickets,seats))
    


    for viewer in viewers:
        print("\nMovie : "+self.movie_name)
        print("name : "+your_name)
        print("Number of Tickets : "+no_of_tickets)
        print("Seat Number : "+seats)
        break



movie_tickets=TenetMovie(input("Which movie would you like to watch : "))
movie_tickets.ticket_buyer()
```

Comment: This question is better suited for codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: you have a if statement and it has a break. Why do you have break for if statement? Did you mean to say `return` instead?

Answer (score 1):

use `return` not `break` when you want to exit a function.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `return` not `break` Because you are not working with a loop, a function.

```
viewers = []
class TenetMovie:
    def __init__(self,movie_name):
        self.movie_name=movie_name


    def ticket_buyer(self):
        print('at any point if you want to exit press "q"') 
        your_name = input("your name : ")
        if your_name == 'q':
            return
        no_of_tickets = input("how many tickets : ")
        if no_of_tickets == 'q':
            return
        seats = input("select the seats : ")
        if seats == 'q':
            return
        viewers.extend((self.movie_name,your_name,no_of_tickets,seats))
    


        for viewer in viewers:
            print("\nMovie : "+self.movie_name)
            print("name : "+your_name)
            print("Number of Tickets : "+no_of_tickets)
            print("Seat Number : "+seats)
            break



movie_tickets=TenetMovie(input("Which movie would you like to watch : "))
movie_tickets.ticket_buyer()
```

Comment: this really works...thank you so much

Comment: @NaveenRK  Glad it helped! Please accept it by clicking on the check mark

Comment: The indentation is wrong. This program can't run because you get an `IndentationError`. And why is the `for viewer in viewers:` loop a part of the class definition?

Comment: @Matthias Oh, thank you for the comment, now it is edited, it should work.